# Google Map on Listing Section Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, plugins

I used [business directory plugin](https://businessdirectoryplugin.com/docs-old/google-maps-module/) which add listing section. Add the listing page, I try to add the map inside the listing page. The map seems to appear inside wordpress directory dashboard but it does not appear in the website. I know that this plugin got google map module, but is there any way to put google map without using the google map addon?Here is my code

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-291" src="https://harta-net.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2018/05/f84590ac-b53e-432d-9137-2241c7075f2d_tb-300x147.jpeg" alt="" width="300" height="147" /></p>
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3984.3164489624587!2d101.61260631430928!3d3.0093049978084196!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cdb36044fe6151%3A0x9c6f6535d01735ff!2sMasteron+Grand+Pavilion!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1526629036980" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

[directory dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnctd.png). [Here is the link of my website](http://harta.net/developer-property-listing/290/permodalan-masteron-sdn-bhd/)

edit: Add the code and the website link

edit 2: try to use other google map plugin to add but still fail

edit 3: I found the problem is because I need to create a section for the google map inside business directory form to make it appears. Additional question, is it possible to only input adddress and auto change it from address to google map?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add this on any page,post or sections of content/text box

```
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3984.3164489624587!2d101.61260631430928!3d3.0093049978084196!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cdb36044fe6151%3A0x9c6f6535d01735ff!2sMasteron+Grand+Pavilion!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1526629036980" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but I think the code is basically the same one with the one that I copy from Google Map itself. Just to be sure I try paste in my coding but it still does not appear in the website but it appear in the directory dashboard section

Comment: where you want to add this in frontend ,,link  please

Comment: sorry i already edit to include my code and the link to my website

Answer (score 0):

Hi Did you added the api key for google maps for specific live url? if not then you have to create and after that you have to mention in your iframe